# Access method of class within class

Tags: c++, class, nested-class

I'm trying to port some code from an older version of a program to a newer version and some things have moved. There is a class called 'Game', and it USED  to contain a method  called ButtonNameToIndex, however in the newer version there is now a class inside the Game class, called 'InputScheme', and ButtonNameToIndex is declared in InputScheme

Game.h:

```
class Game
{
public:
   const char *     m_szName;
   const Style * const* m_apStyles;
   bool         m_bCountNotesSeparately;
   bool         m_bAllowHopos;
   InputScheme      m_InputScheme;
}
```

InputScheme.h:

```
class InputScheme
{
public:
    const char  *m_szName;
    int     m_iButtonsPerController;
    struct GameButtonInfo
    {
        const char  *m_szName;
        GameButton  m_SecondaryMenuButton;
    };

    GameButtonInfo m_GameButtonInfo[NUM_GameButton];
    const InputMapping *m_Maps;

    GameButton ButtonNameToIndex( const RString &sButtonName ) const;
}
```

The code I am trying to port looks like this:

```
FOREACH_ENUM( GameButton, pGame->ButtonNameToIndex("Operator"), gb )
    ini.SetValue( sPlayerKey, GameButtonToString(pGame, gb),
        FromMapping(mapping.m_iGameLights[gc][gb]) );
```

I can't work out how to access ButtonNameToIndex now that it has moved to a new class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `Game` class has a public member variable of type `InputScheme` you can replace any calls to

```
pGame->ButtonNameToIndex("Operator")
```

with

```
pGame->m_InputScheme.ButtonNameToIndex("Operator")
```

we use `->` to access the member of `Game` since we are accessing through a pointer (I assume), since `m_InputScheme` is a value (not pointer) we access its member function using the `.` operator